# Why can't the root IAM account view stuff created by IAM user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'm having problems with AWS, that I guess is somehow related to IAM. I'm afraid I might be missing something obvious here, but I can't find it anywhere.

Here's what I did:

- logged into the AWS console with the root account
- created an IAM group with full administrative access
- created a user `jeff` in this group
- logged out of the root account
- logged in as `jeff`
- created a bunch of stuff, including an AMI, an RDS instance, load balancer, launch configuration, auto scaling groups, etc.

When I logout `jeff` and login as the root account, I see none of this. For example, `jeff` sees that there's 1 running RDS instance, 1 running EBS instance, 1 launch configuration defined, etc. But the root account sees zeros everywhere. In fact, the only VPC id that the root account sees is a different VPC id that the one `jeff` sees.

What's going on here? Why can't the root account see anything? Is there a setting that I can change? Lastly, if I make another IAM user, will they be able to see `jeff`'s stuff?

Comment: Are you sure that you've selected the correct region when signing in as the root user?

Comment: @EEAA, that was totally it—thank you! If you write that up as the answer, I'll approve it.

Comment: Done. Glad to have helped! I've been caught off guard several times by this as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Verify that you've selected the correct region when signing in.